# Python3 SSL urllib error

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, urllib

I receive the following error while attempting to execute a python3 wrapper script.

```
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: TLSV1_UNRECOGNIZED_NAME] unknown error (_ssl.c:600)>
```

I am unsure if this is related to a misconfiguration with python or my network. The system has both Python 2.7 and 3.4 installed and is behind a proxy. Are there any commands I can execute to test urllib from python3?

pip freeze lists urllib3 however I believe this lib was installed for Python 2.7

Comment: To test ssl in `urllib` try `urllib.request.urlopen('https://google.com').read()`

Comment: >>> urllib.request.urlopen('https://google.com').read()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'urllib' is not defined

Comment: Import `urllib` before…

Comment: >>> import urllib
>>> urllib.request.urlopen('https://google.com').read()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'request'

Comment: when I import urllib.request it works. Thanks for the test